# Correct Way of Creating a Defensive Copy of Custom Class

Tags: c#, class, defensive-copy

I've got the following class:

```
public class FolderAgent
    {
        public string directoryName {get; private set; }
        public int numberofdirectories {get; private set; }
        public int numberofFiles {get; private set;}
        public DirectoryInfo [] directories {get; private set;}
        public FileInfo [] files {get; private set;}

        public FolderAgent(string directoryName, int numberofdirectories, int numberofFiles, DirectoryInfo [] listDir, FileInfo [] listFiles)
        {
            this.directoryName = directoryName;
            this.numberofdirectories = numberofdirectories;
            this.numberofFiles = numberofFiles;
            Array.Copy(listDir, directories, listDir.Length);
            Array.Copy(listFiles, files, listFiles.Length);
        }
    }
```

I have another class that will take folderagent as a parameter in the constructor, is this the correct way of creating a defensive copy of the Folderagent object?

```
public class FolderKey
    {

        public FolderAgent folder {get; private set;}
        public int returnValue {get; private set;}

        public FolderKey(FolderAgent folder, int returnValue)
        {
            this.folder = new FolderAgent(folder.directoryName, folder.numberofdirectories, folder.numberofFiles, folder.directories, folder.files);
            this.returnValue = returnValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are close, if not correct... you will get a copy for each name, numberOfDir, and numberOfFiles. You will also create new arrays for both your `DirectoryInfo[]` and `FileInfo[]`. However, every single element of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` in your `FileInfo[]` and `DirectoryInfo[]` will still share the same reference to the original folder... Which should not be an issue as long as you do not mean to write anything to them.

Comment: @Ian - Could you show me how to create a defensive copy of arrays then, because I intend to delete the files and folders in directory provided.

Comment: @Ian - I think array.clone is the proper choice here.

Comment: What you have done for array is actually okay, it is correct - you have duplicated your array. What happen in one array (such as you put it to null), will not affect another array. But the element of the array in you case is `class`, these are the ones which are not copied, and making defensive copy of a `class` is really troublesome. You can check some other posts to find out a good strategy though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954791/how-do-i-make-defensive-copy-of-an-object?rq=1

Comment: If, by the time you create your defensive copy, all `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` structures are "valid" (i.e., you just created those objects so the cached data in them is current), then making a copy would be trivial: just create new instances with the path in the original files. Using "unrefreshed" instances of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` is not really all that common (that's why `Refresh` exists on them)

Comment: @Jcl - Could you change my code and show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want a copy of all elements of the array. Note that `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` use cached data which gets initialized the first time you access any of the file/directory properties.

So you might just aswell recreate the objects, instead of making a copy... something like (untested):

```
public FolderAgent(string directoryName, int numberofdirectories,
                   int numberofFiles, DirectoryInfo [] listDir, 
                   FileInfo [] listFiles)
{
    this.directoryName = directoryName;
    this.numberofdirectories = numberofdirectories;
    this.numberofFiles = numberofFiles;

    directories = new DirectoryInfo[listDir.length];
    for(var i = 0; i < listDir.length; i++)
      directories[i] = new DirectoryInfo(listDir[i].FullName);

    files = new FileInfo[listFiles.length];
    for(var i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++)
      files[i] = new FileInfo(listFiles[i].FullName);
}
```

Comment: How would [i] get incremented?

Comment: Ooops, my bad, I made a `for` loop, then changed to `foreach` but didn't think about that. **Updated**

Comment: Note that I haven't tested this, but it *should* work. Then again, all properties involving file/directory attributes of `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` will get cached the first time you access any of those properties, so you can't count on those properties being equal if your filesystem has changed. Then again, that's not the mission of `DirectoryInfo` or `FileInfo`, so if you need that (caching of the file/directory data), you'd be better off creating your own classes, instead of relying on those

Comment: @Spaceman A side note too (but that depends on what you want this for), `numberofFiles` and `numberofdirectories` might be redundant to have if they are just the length of the arrays

Comment: I'm creating a small utility for clearing a folder, and have to determine if files/sub directories exist. If it's greater than 0 then we have files/folders, but I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: And you need to store all the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` structures and make a defensive copy for that?

Comment: Not really, I learned about defensive copying for immutable objects and wanted to learn how to implement it in my own projects.

Comment: Ok if it's for learning purposes. Be wary though, `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` are far from immutable. If anything, they are one of the most mutable classes in the .NET Framework. Almost all their properties will change their state based on many different external factors (like... the filesystem) :-)